# About the return type of an unbound template friend function of a template class

Tags: c++, class, templates, c++11, friend-function

Suppose I have a template class which has a template friend function hoping to implement the function of a value multiplying an array(myArray):

```
template<typename T, int size>
class myArray{
  T *_array;
public:
  ...
  template<typename Val, typename Array> 
  friend myArray<T,size> operator*(const Val &lhs, const Array &rhs){
    myArray<T,size> mat_t;
    for(int i = 0;i < size; i++)
      mat_t._array[i] = lhs * rhs._array[i];
    return mat_t;
}
  ...
};
```

It works on VS2013. Then I move the definition of the unbound template friend function outside:

```
template<typename Val, typename Array>
myArray<T,size> operator*(const Val &lhs, const Array &rhs){
  myArray<T,size> mat_t;
  for(int i = 0;i < size; i++)
    mat_t._array[i] = lhs * rhs._array[i];
  return mat_t;
}
```

It is incorrect! I suppose the problem is with the return type of the friend function. But I can't not figure it out.
So how to define a friend template function like this outside the class declaration?

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Template friends can be [notoriously difficult](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#template-friends) to get right. Post your error and friend declaration for the second case.

Comment: What do you expect T and size to be?  What do you want to support Array being?  Maybe you only intended Array to be another myArray<T,size> in which case, you should have specified that.  But if you expect the return of the function to vary in type independently of the input type, then you need to specify it (and then it can't be deduced).

Comment: @tobi303 My question is how to define that friend function outside the class declaration.

Comment: @TartanLlama The friend declaration is inside the class as above, just removing the definition. And the errors are like  " T invalid and size undeclared" .

Comment: @JSF Yes, I intend Array to be another myArray<T,size>, thus implementing the function of val*myArray. So how should I define the friend function outside?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`friend` functions declared like the first example are strange beasts.  Each instance of `myArray<T,Size>` creates a **distinct** `friend` function that can only be found via argument dependent lookup on `myArray<T,Size>`.

A free `operator*` not declared that way does not work that way.

You can get your code to work like this:

```
template<class Val, class T, int size>
myArray<T,size> operator*(const Val &lhs, const myArray<T,size> &rhs){
  myArray<T,size> mat_t;
  for(int i = 0;i < size; i++)
    mat_t._array[i] = lhs * rhs._array[i];
  return mat_t;
}
```

here all of the template parameters are listed in the `template<>` list, and they are all deducible from the arguments to `*`.

Remember to put your `operator*` in the same namespace as `myArray`.

However, personally, I'd go with:

```
friend myArray operator*(const T&lhs, const myArray &rhs){
  myArray mat_t;
  for(int i = 0;i < size; i++)
    mat_t._array[i] = lhs * rhs._array[i];
  return mat_t;
}
```

a non-`template` friend `operator*`.  Again, one of these is "spawned" for each `myArray<T,size>`, but it itself is not a `template`.  This has certain advantages, such as it behaves nicer with conversion constructors.

Going a step further, we get:

```
friend myArray& operator*=(myArray&mat, const T&scalar){
  for(int i = 0;i < size; i++)
    mat._array[i] *= scalar;
  return mat;
}
friend myArray operator*(const T&scalar, myArray mat){
  mat *= scalar;
  return mat;
}
friend myArray operator*(myArray mat, const T&scalar){
  mat *= scalar;
  return mat;
}
```

where we first create a `*=`, then write `*` in terms of it.  Notice that `*` takes `myArray` by-value (because I need to return a copy anyhow, might as well have it happen outside the method), and I support both `mat*scalar` and `scalar*mat` and `mat*=scalar`.

Also note that matrices of matrices ... just work.

The reason why this `friend operator` is a good idea is illustrated [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d9dfd0e3bd32b6c7).  Note the code does not compile.  Now [`#define ADL` to move the `operator*` into the class as `friends`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cb242df537746ab6) and it compiles.  Koenig operators let `operator*` operate on a `template` class without being a template, and argument matching rules for templates are hard to get right without being overly narrow, overly broad, or using nasty SFINAE.

Next step, `operator*=` can be improved via: (C++14 used for brevity)

```
template<class Array
  class=std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<std::decay_t<Array>,myArray>>
>
friend Array operator*=(Array&&mat, const T&scalar){
  for(int i = 0;i < size; i++)
    mat._array[i] *= scalar;
  return std::forward<Array>(mat);
}
```

which is more complex, but does fun things with perfect forwarding.  A temporary `myArray` gets `move`d into the return value (which allows for reference lifetime extension to work), while non-temporary `myArray` return a reference.

This provides a reason why even `*=` should be a `friend`.  It allows both r and lvalues to be implemented in the same method.

On the other hand, possibly you don't want `*=` to work with rvalues.  In that case, use a regular method with a `&` reference-category qualifier to eliminate that choice.

Comment: There is no need for `operator*=` being a free friend function, it can and should be just a plain member function. There also is no need for the `operator*` to be a friend at all, unless you decide to not make `operator*=` public.

Comment: @ArneMertz I call that technique Koenig operators.  [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cb242df537746ab6) compiles, while [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d9dfd0e3bd32b6c7) does not, the only difference is one case we have a Koenig `friend operator*`, and the other case we have a free `template operator*`.  There are good reasons to use `friend operator`s with `template` types: `template` functions tend to be under-specified or over-specified or have nasty SFINAE requirements.  `operator*=` can probably be a plain-old method, but perfect forwarding self also rocks.

Comment: @Yakk I just cannot get your first example to work. You did give a nice solution in the following examples using non-template friend functions, which, however, also have problems when defining outside. With template friend function, I have just worked it out by changing the declaration as `template<typename Val, typename Array> 
  friend Array operator*(const Val &lhs, const Array &rhs)` and defining the `mat_t` in the body with type `Array`. But how to define your non-template friend function outside?

Comment: @Shindou the non-template friend functions cannot be defined outside:  The best you can do is dispatch (call) some other external function (or method).  Often I call it "increment_by" for `+=`, then have `operator*=` and `operator*` be implemented as 1-3 line functions.

Answer (score 0):

`T` and `size` are template parameters of `myArray`. If you put a definition of a function that containse those template parameters outside of the defintion of `myArray`, you have to state again, that they are template parameters, e.g.

```
template <typename T, int size, typename Val, typename Array>
```

However, that won't help you much, even if you get it to compile, because you won't be able to actually call the operator correctly, since the compiler can not deduce the template arguments `T` and `size`. The call would have to be something awkward like

```
auto a = operator*<double, 4>(22, someArray);
```

You probably want to make a function that only returns the same type as its second argument - anything else would not make much sense anyways. To avoid difficulties with template friend declarations (which are hard to get right) and the tight coupling you get with friends, you could relay the operator to a public multiplication function or, better yet, operator*=

```
template<typename T, int size>
class myArray {
  T *_array;
public:
  myArray() : _array(new T[size]{22}) {}
  //...
  template<typename Val> 
  myArray& operator*=(const Val &val) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) 
      _array[i] *= val  ;
    return *this;
  }
};

template <typename Val, typename T, int size>
myArray<T,size> operator*(const Val &lhs, myArray<T, size> tmp) {
  tmp *= lhs; 
  return tmp;
}
```

For a rationale why `operator*=` should be a member function and not a free friend function see [this link](http://arne-mertz.de/2015/01/operator-overloading-common-practice/#operator-3)

Comment: Can you demonstrate an example of an implicit type conversion to a `myArray&` that binds it to a temporary and causes a problem with a `friend operator*=`?  Between the requirement that it be an lvalue, and only being accessible via Koenig lookup, it doesn't seem possible.

Comment: @Yakk See [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b59b9a50abf8493d) fore examples how conversions can result in an unexpected call of `operator*=`

Comment: The Y case makes no difference member or not.  [And the `Z` case doesn't work with a `friend operator*=` (Koenig style).](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fa48beae40d6a2b1).  So why prefer member `*=` over Koenig-style `friend *=`?